# Как изменить тип множества переменных в одной строке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, map, типы-данных, множества

Как с помощью минимального количества кода изменить тип множества переменных?

Знаю что-то типа `a, b, c = map(int, input().split())`, но не знаю, как с помощью того же можно сделать изменение типа множества переменных, если дополнительно ничего не нужно делать?

Пробовал это: `a, b, c = map(str)`, на что система мне любезно ответила, что должно быть два аргумента у map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так:

```
a, b, c = map(str, [a, b, c])
```

Либо без `map` с помощью списковых включений:

```
a, b, c = [str(x) for x in [a, b, c]]
```